# Can you add an object to an arraycollection inside an arraycollection?

Tags: apache-flex, arraycollection

I have tried adding an object to an ArrayCollection inside an ArrayCollection and it isn't working.  I am getting Error #1009 with the following implementation:

```
for (var x:Number = 0; x < identifyArrayCollection.length; x++)
{
    identifyArrayCollection[x].speedsArrayCollection.addItem(speedsObj);
}
```

I can add the speedsObj to an ArrayCollection that is not inside an ArrayCollection.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 0):

The following code adds the item `speedObj` to the `ArrayCollection` found at index `x` of the `ArrayCollection` called  `identifyArrayCollection`.

```
identifyArrayCollection.getItemAt(x).addItem(speedsObj);
```

Is this what you're looking for?

---

The code you have does the following:

```
identifyArrayCollection[x] 
//accesses the item stored in identifyArrayCollection 
//with the key of the current value of x
//NOT the item stored at index x

.speedsArrayCollection
//accesses the speedsArrayCollection field of the object
//returned from identifyArrayCollection[x]

.addItem(speedsObj)
//this part is "right", add the item speedsObj to the
//ArrayCollection
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that 
identifyArrayCollection is an ArrayCollection containing some Objects and
speedsArrayCollection is an ArrayCollection defined as variable of the Object type that are contained in the identifyArrayCollection

you should do:

```
for (var x:Number = 0; x < identifyArrayCollection.length; x++)
{
    identifyArrayCollection.getItemAt(x).speedsArrayCollection.addItem(speedsObj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that any compound object needs to be initialized as such first.
For example (assuming initial run):

there is two ways you can do this: piggy-backing of @Sam

```
for (var x:Number = 0; x < identifyArrayCollection.length; x++)
{
   if (!identifyArrayCollection[x]) identifyArrayCollection[x] = new ArrayCollection();
   identifyArrayCollection[x].addItem(speedsObj);
}
```

or using an anonymous object if you really want to use explicit naming conventions - however be aware these are **NOT** compile time checked (nor is anything using the array accessor):

```
for (var x:Number = 0; x < identifyArrayCollection.length; x++)
{
   if (!identifyArrayCollection[x]) 
   {
      var o:Object = {};
          o.speedsArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
      identifyArrayCollection[x] = o;
   }
   identifyArrayCollection[x].speedsArrayCollection.addItem(speedsObj);
}
```